# bundle.js não atualiza junto com index.js

Tags: javascript

Não tenho muito conhecimento em programação ainda, gostaria de saber como faço para poder fazer os valores do bundle.js atualizar quando eu mudar os valores no meu index.js

No caso esse código é de uma calculadora e ao mudar os valores desse objeto que esta no index.js precisava que ele mudasse no bundle.js também:

```
const precoKForte = {
  mg: 516,
  sp: 513,
  go: 519,
  mt: 545,
  ms: 525,
};
```

bundle.js :

```
precoKforte:{mg:516,sp:513,go:519,mt:545,ms:525},
```

Answer (score 0):

Aí depende do script que você está executando para desenvolver. Normalmente module bundlers (como webpack), ou até task managers (como o gulp), trazem opções para fazer "watch", que é monitorar os arquivos do projeto, e quando estes são salvos, eles atualizam seus scripts de desenvolvimento.

Mas normalmente, eles não mudam o bundle.js, esse só é gerado na hora do build, ao entregar uma versão nova, no deploy.